# Responsive Animated Background in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

After following the instructions here: https://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css

I can make the picture move, but I cannot figure out how to make it responsive. Any ideas on how to make this possible? I have added following css code:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground{
  from {background-position: 0 0;}
  to {background-position: -1920px 0;}
}


#animate-area{ 
  width: 560px; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-image: url("images/japan.jpg");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of  your code???

Comment: Given url in your description provide such kind of good example. Follow the demo. Compare your code with demo.

Comment: Just make your div responsive. Background will set according to that.

Comment: How do you make the div responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Within the demo, the width of `<div id="animate-area">` is explicitly set to 560px. Try setting it to `width: auto;`. This should scale the div width to that of it's container/parent.